# Align Bullet Point with paragraph text

Tags: itemize, enumitem

I am using graphics as my bullet points. I would like the image to center on the text instead of be at the top of the text. For example here is my code:

```
    \documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \newcommand*{\drugs}{%
 \item[{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm]{figs/drugs.png}}]%
} \newcommand*{\mental}{%
 \item[{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm]{figs/mentalhealth.png}}]%
}\newcommand*{\nut}{%
 \item[{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm]{figs/nutandfit.png}}]%
}\newcommand*{\care}{%
 \item[{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm]{figs/care.png}}]%
}\newcommand*{\health}{%
 \item[{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm]{figs/healthicon.png}}]%
}\newcommand*{\economy}{%
 \item[{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm]{figs/economy.png}}]%
}

 \begin{document}
 \textbf{\textit{Health Priorities}}
 \begin{itemize}
\drugs \textbf{\textit{Substance Abuse and Misuse}} includes the use of alcohol, tobacco and e-cigarettes, prescription drugs, opioids and other drugs in a manner that is harmful, or causes problems or distress, to a person's health and/or daily life. 
\mental \textbf{\textit{Mental Health}} is the connection between mental illness, community stigma, social and community support, resiliency, and overall mental and emotional well-being. 
\nut \textbf{\textit{Nutrition and Physical Activity}} means the ability to access nutrition, physical activity and supportive resources for families and communities. 
 \end{itemize}

 \textbf{\textit{Social Determinants of Health}}
 \begin{itemize}
\economy \textbf{\textit{Economic stability }} influences the ability to access both mental and physical healthcare, nutritious foods, and physical activity opportunities. 
\care \textbf{\textit{Health care and quality/access to care}} means having equal access to convenient, quality, and affordable care for all that is trauma informed and culturally responsive. This includes factors such as proximity to care, diversity training for staff, diverse backgrounds of providers, cost of care, insurance coverage, medical transportation, and care coordination within the health care system.  
\health \textbf{\textit{Education}} influences mental and physical heath, economic stability, access to healthcare, substance abuse and misuse, and health equity.  
\end{itemize}
```

This results in a PDF like this:
[image]

I would like it to look like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `\raisebox{-.6cm}{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm]{figs/healthicon.png}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The figures were vertically aligned with the text using two side-by-side `minipages`.  The text is inserted via the mandatory parameter defined in each command.

Finally, the figures are left flush with the left margin using a global setting for `itemize`:

`\setlist[itemize]{<options>}`

The new defined length `\LabWidth` allows you to choose the width of the images.

The solution will maintain the requested alignment regardless of the number of lines of text or the width of the figures (try it!).

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{showframe}% ONLY to show the margins

\newlength{\LabWidth}
\setlength{\LabWidth}{1.2cm}% set the labels widths <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\newcommand*{\drugs}[1]{%
\item[{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\includegraphics[width=\LabWidth]{example-image-a}\end{minipage}}]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}
}

\newcommand*{\mental}[1]{% changed <<<<<<
\item[{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\includegraphics[width=\LabWidth]{example-image-b}\end{minipage}}]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}
}

\newcommand*{\nut}[1]{%changed <<<<<<
\item[{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\includegraphics[width=\LabWidth]{example-image-c}\end{minipage}}]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}
}

\newcommand*{\care}[1]{%changed <<<<<<
\item[{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\includegraphics[width=\LabWidth]{example-image-b}\end{minipage}}]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}
}

\newcommand*{\health}[1]{%changed <<<<<<
\item[{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\includegraphics[width=\LabWidth]{example-image-c}\end{minipage}}]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}
}

\newcommand*{\economy}[1]{%changed <<<<<<
\item[{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\includegraphics[width=\LabWidth]{example-image-a}\end{minipage}}]
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}
}

\setlist[itemize]{align=parleft, labelwidth=\LabWidth, leftmargin =\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}% global setting

\begin{document}
    \textbf{\textit{Health Priorities}}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \drugs{\textbf{\textit{Substance Abuse and Misuse}} includes the use of alcohol, tobacco and e-cigarettes, prescription drugs, opioids and other drugs in a manner that is harmful, or causes problems or distress, to a person's health and/or daily life. }           
        \mental{\textbf{\textit{Mental Health}} is the connection between mental illness, community stigma, social and community support, resiliency, and overall mental and emotional well-being.}             
        \nut{\textbf{\textit{Nutrition and Physical Activity}} means the ability to access nutrition, physical activity and supportive resources for families and communities.}
    \end{itemize}
    
    \textbf{\textit{Social Determinants of Health}}

    \begin{itemize}
        \economy{\textbf{\textit{Economic stability}} influences the ability to access both mental and physical healthcare, nutritious foods, and physical activity opportunities.}
        \care{\textbf{\textit{Health care and quality/access to care}} means having equal access to convenient, quality, and affordable care for all that is trauma informed and culturally responsive. This includes factors such as proximity to care, diversity training for staff, diverse backgrounds of providers, cost of care, insurance coverage, medical transportation, and care coordination within the health care system.}
        \health{\textbf{\textit{Education}} influences mental and physical heath, economic stability, access to healthcare, substance abuse and misuse, and health equity.}
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Since the code defines 6 almost identical commands, it could be simplified by using a single command with two required parameters: the first with the name of the image and the second with the text.  Like

```
\newcommand{\itemx}[2]{%
        \item[{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\includegraphics[width=\LabWidth]{figs/#1.png}\end{minipage}}]
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}#2\end{minipage}
}
```

So you could use for Education

```
\itemx{healthicon}{\textbf{\textit{Education}} influences mental and physical heath, economic stability, access to healthcare, substance abuse and misuse, and health equity.}
```